# compiling java package classes. Cannot access Class. class file contains wrong class while working with packages

Tags: java

I was trying to compile a few files in a package in java. The package name is `library`. Please have a look at the following details.

This is my Directory Structure:

```
javalearning
---library
------ParentClass.java
------ChildClass.java
```

I tried to compile in the following way:

current directory: `javalearning`

```
javac library/ParentClass.java   //this compilation works fine 
javac library/ChildClass.java    //error over here
```

The following is the `ParentClass.java`:

```
package library;
class Parentclass{
...
}
```

The following is the `ChildClass.java`:

```
package library;
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
...
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
cannot access ParentClass
bad class file: .\library\ParentClass.class
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct sub directory of the classpath
```

Comment: Note that although this is a typo question effectively, I think it's worth answering anyway as it's a reasonably easy typo to make and a relatively tricky one to diagnose. That's assuming the code is actually as stated in the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a casing issue:

```
class Parentclass
```

That's not the same as the filename `ParentClass.class`, nor is it the same as the class you're trying to use in `ChildClass`: `class ChildClass extends ParentClass`.

Java classnames are case-sensitive, but Windows filenames aren't. If the class had been public, the compiler would have validated that the names matched - but for non-public classes, there's no requirement for that.

The fact that you've ended up with `ParentClass.class` suggests that at *some* point it was declared as `ParentClass`, but then you changed the declared name and when recompiling, Windows just overwrote the content of the current file rather than effectively creating `Parentclass.class`.

Make sure your declared class name *exactly* matches the filename. You may well want to delete all your class files before recompiling, just to get out of a confusing state.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when making the class `public`, the compiler **does** complain when compiling `ParentClass.java` (`library\ParentClass.java:2: error: class Parentclass is public, should be declared in a file named Parentclass.java`

Comment: @AndreasFester: Ah, I'd missed that it wasn't public - that explains it. Will edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet changed the Parentclass to ParentClass and deleted class files and recompiled but still struck with the same error. Also found that the it is working fine without any package specifications.

Comment: @sandilya: I can't reproduce that. I suggest you create a new directory with minimal *complete* sample code and try to reproduce the error from scratch, documenting what you're doing. It sounds like you still have some bad class (or source) files *somewhere*.

Comment: @JonSkeet It compiled well. May be you are right regarding bad classes still being present in my source. Thanks for helping.